# method = RequestMethod.POST and model.addAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, model-view-controller

I am relatively new to java world. 
I am using Spring MVC (using 4.0.2) Maven...

1) I have jsp file which sends json data [A] to controller (POST)

2) then, Controller(method) calculates another value based on the data from jsp

3) I need to return the another value (the result of calculation) [B] to jsp by model.addAtrribute.

but It doesn't return by model. Here is my code.

### In JSP file (original trial)

```
 $.ajax({
                url:'/mypage.html',
                    data: 'left=' + left +'&right='+ right,  ----[A1]
                    type:"POST",
                    success: function(json){
                    //alert('succeed!');
                    }   
                  });
    .........
    .........
<p style="color:red; font-size: 12pt">Distance: ${distance}</p>  --- [B1]
```

so now controller:

### In controller (original trial)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mypage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestBody String  response, Model model) {

    String left = … response parsing…...;   ---[A2] //works fine  
    String right = … response parsing...; -----[A2] //works fine

    String distance = getDistance(left, right);   // [B2] is calculated for distance based on [A2], works fine

    model.addAttribute("distance", distance);   --- [B2]

    Return "mypage";  // [B2] should be delivered to [B1] (in jsp) and display ${distance} value
}
```

I have simplified my code because response, parsing parts are working fine.

I think it's something wrong about **(my suspicion part)**:

===> 'method=RequestMethod.post' and 'model.addAttribute'

or

===> return "mypage" and [B1] part in jsp

If anyone can point out what I did wrong, really appreciated.

====================== Solved !!!! =====================

I add my solution here, just in case, 
if anyone need to use this kind technique as well....

Thanks to both @willysama and @misko321 for good answers & pointing out what  can and can't and providing sample code.

[Solution]

### In controller (final solution)

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/mypage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String update(@RequestBody String  response) {
        String left = … response parsing…...;      
        String right = … response parsing...;  
        String distance = getDistance(left, right);   //e.g. distance = 100

        return distance;    // simply return String value of distance
                            // don't need to have model.addAttribute
    }
```

### In JSP file (final solution)

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'/mypage.html',
            data: 'left=' + left +'&right='+ right, 
            type:"POST",
            success: function(response){   // here should be 'response'
             //here gets from controller
            alert('what I get?response='+response);  //what I get? response=100
            $('#distance_result').text(response);  // to [1] for refreshing distance value 

            }   
        });
    ......
    ......
    <p style="color:red; font-size: 12pt">Distance: <span id="distance_result">${distance}</span></p>   // [1] refresh the distance value which returned from controller
```

(simple comments for the solution)
I don't need to deliver the distance value through model.addAttribute.

The update method in controller when I post has String return value (public @ResponseBody **String** update....), 
so I just need to return String (which is 'distance' here) to jsp

then in jsp , 
'ajax success:' part will receive this return 'distance' from controller in success which both @willysama and @misko321 pointed out. like below:

```
success: function(response){   
                $('#distance_result').text(response);
```

so in the end, the place to refresh the distance value..

```
<p style="color:red; font-size: 12pt">Distance: <span id="distance_result">${distance}</span></p>
```

works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way. You are trying to change dynamically a value in your jsp already loaded from the server. The only manner to do it is in your javascript with the return of your ajax call.

Put a specific tag or class where you want to set the value asynchronously :

```
<p style="color:red; font-size: 12pt">Distance: <span id="distance_result">${distance}</span></p>
```

And update your success function to use the response from the server and set it where needed:

```
success: function(json){
    $('#distance_result').text(json.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I did not know that I can't refresh value on already loaded jsp page. I have tried your answer and put your suggested code (please check 'here' part in the edited part in the origianl question.). but I have no luck to succeed. It does not refresh the distance value.. any other advices?

Comment: Can you check the [why?] part as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you make an Ajax call, not a standard request. So the page `mypage` is returned to Ajax success function:

```
success: function(json) {
//alert('succeed!');
} ),
```

as an already rendered html, but the page is not refreshed.
I think you should return only a JSON or even a simple String and then parse it inside `success` function. Then you can substitute the old value with the new one.
Alternatively you can make a redirect to the same page after Ajax success to refresh the page or not make an Ajax call, but a standard POST request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your suggestion (check here in the edited part in the question) : added response inside success (jsp side) redirected the page (controller side).. but no luck. it doesn't refresh the page... any other adivices? and you mentioned about a standard request instead of an Ajax call... what is a standard request? how can I do that in code?